# From apache sling launchpad 7 to sling 11

Tags: sling, jackrabbit, jackrabbit-oak

I have to upgrade an app than run on Apache Sling and Apache Jackrabbit. It uses the launchpad 7 webapp (`org.apache.sling.launchpad-7.war`) and the persistence is configured to use Jackrabbit (not Oak), with a workspace stored inside an Oracle database and data stored on the filesytem.

I have seen that newer versions of apache sling do not support Jackrabbit any more, they only support Jackrabbit Oak.

What would be the best way to upgrade Apache Sling on my app ?

1. Is it mandatory to use Apache Oak with Sling now ?
2. What would be the best (or simplest) way to configure Apache Sling ?
3. I have 700MB of data stored in jackrabbit, is there any tool to migrate all that data ?

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean by "What would be the best (or simplest) way to configure Apache Sling ?"?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding Jackrabbit vs Jackrabbit Oak: we do not test Jackrabbit 2.x with Sling at all. It may work by replacing various bundles, there are no guarantees.

For the repository, the migration tools are provided by the Jackrabbit project: see [Oak: repository migration](https://jackrabbit.apache.org/oak/docs/migration.html) where the `oak-upgrade` tool is documented. You probably need to look into the `DocumentNodeStore` with a RDB setup. The [Oak: RDB document store](https://jackrabbit.apache.org/oak/docs/nodestore/document/rdb-document-store.html) documentation will tell you more about supported databases (Oracle is one of them) and how to configure them.

Note that we don't have an RDB runmode set up for the Sling 11 starter, but I guess you did that for Sling 7 as well.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "did that for sling 7 as well". Here sling 7 was installed in 2014 by someone that is long gone. What am I supposed to do to add an RDB runmode to sling web launchpad ?

Comment: (What was done with sling 7 was only configuring Jackarabbit's repository.xml configuration file, there was nothing about modifying Sling's runmode)

Comment: I have the same question, but in my case I want to upgrade an application form Sling 7 (Oak 1.6.1) to Sling 11. Sure, the application codebase needs to be updated, but what are the options for upgrading existing instances?